# Two Images folder in 12 hive

Tags: 2007, image, hive

Just wondering if someone knows why exactly we got two "Images" folders in 12 hive in SharePoint 2007.

One is

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server
>   extensions\12\TEMPLATE\IMAGES

and second one I noticed is at

> \12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\LCID\IMAGES

I know 2nd one could be related to a specific language but having it in

> \12\TEMPLATE\IMAGES

shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint place the images at following path

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server
>   extensions\12\TEMPLATE\IMAGES

Hence you can refer the image as `<img src="/_layouts/images/test.jpg" />`. But, instead create a custom folder under IMAGES folder and change reference accordingly.

The second path contains the language identifier with each language pack being installed in SP Farm like

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server
>   extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\Images

(Note: 1033 is the language identified for the English version)